# Is a bystander liable to be arrested for interfering in an undercover cop's operation?

Tags: police, undercover

If for example, a random person passing by happens to see some altercation between some undercover cops and a suspect and they wrongfully assumed that the suspect was being ganged upon, will they get in trouble if they started interfering with the operation? (For example, running in and sucker punching the cop)